Is there a way to hide in-scene lights in reflections?
I have a scene with lights that are placed in camera view.  The lights themselves don't show up in the camera, but their reflections show up in the windows of the scene.  Example:

Is there an easy way to keep these lights from reflecting in reflective surfaces?  I found this but it seems to only apply to objects, and it's actually the inverse of what I need.
[EDIT:  Ideally it would be possible to do this in both EEVEE and Cycles but the final render will be in Cycles, so if it can only be done in Cycles that would be fine.]

Are you using EEVEE or Cycles?

@moonboots Which Diffuse value of the light?

Sorry I meant the Specular value of the light in Eevee only

If on Cycles, you could go in the object properties > Visibility panel > Ray Visibility panel, and disable Glossy:

If on Eevee, you can set the light's specular property to zero:

In both cases, this makes the lamp appear in no reflections at all.
If you want to more precisely decide where to show in reflections or not, a way around could be to use Light linking, but this would remove all light effects on the designated objects. So it works best if you have objects with just one glass-like material that doesn't need any lighting in the first place. I.E. if you have a window: make sure you separate the glass part into a different object without the frame and whatnot.
Make a collection, and additively add to it the objects you don't want to receive light from your light source.
Then select the light, go to its object properties > Shading panel > Light Linking sub panel. Add the collection you just made. You should see a list of the objects you put there. Uncheck them to exclude them from receiving light from this light object.



That worked like a charm!  Thank you, you've saved me an immense amount of time.
